# Coldfusion, help creating a download all button that will zip all the CSV files that are created from a query

Tags: csv, coldfusion

Right now I have a query that will give me results that are broken down into 2000 rows of results. For example if the query is run and there are 16000 results it will break this down into 2000 results per CSV file that the user can download, so there would be 8 download buttons. When the user press the download button it creates a CSV file.

I currently use this in coldfusion to generate the CSV

```
<cflock name="SFSchoolList" timeout="20" type="exclusive">
   <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=UserList.csv">
   <cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel">
   <cfoutput>firstname,lastname,email,username,password#chr(13)##chr(10)#</cfoutput>
   <cfloop query="SF">
      <cfoutput>#TRIM(firstname)#,#TRIM(lastname)#,#TRIM(email)#,#TRIM(username)#,#TRIM(password)##chr(13)##chr(10)#</cfoutput>
   </cfloop>
 </cflock>
```

This will loop through the SF query to create the CSV when the user clicks the download button from the from.

My question is, how do I go about rewriting this to have it query those results automatically when they press the generate button, when pressed it will write all the possible files to a folder on our server and zip it allowing the user to press a download all button and download the zip instead of individually clicking every download button?

Let me know if you need more code or description on this and I will provide as much as I can. Thanks!

Comment: You seem to know exactly what you need to do here and it's not a complex arrangement. What have you tried involving CFZIP?

Comment: That's the thing I feel like I know what I'm doing and I've gotten it to work with xls files but for some reason when I try using the csv it will not work. I've used the cfspreadsheet with the xls and have gotten the files to write to the server but only when the button is clicked to download and not when generated. Which is what I would like it to do.

Comment: Phrases like "will not work" are very ambiguous. What is the actual result of your code? What should it be instead? Also, rather than describing the code - please just post it. Obviously narrow it down to the relevant parts.

Comment: Why are you breaking up the csv file to start with?   Why not simply have one file with all the data?

Comment: I am breaking up the csv files because the person who uses this uploads these files to another site which will only allow 2000 rows at a time. So when the query is 15,000 to 25,000 it gets broken into 2000 result csv files. If that makes sense.

Comment: If the person does nothing other than uploading the files to another site, can you not use cfhttp to upload the files for him?

Comment: Hmm I never thought about doing it that way, would it be hard to use cfhttp when it is a site outside of our own?

Comment: You'll have to try it and see.  I suggest asking the people in charge of the other site if there is a test page you can use.

Comment: Okay I'll do that, for now though can you explain how I can have the files write to a directory without the user having to press the download button in the form?

Comment: There is a cffile tag for that.