# Separating Query in multiple CSV Files Using ColdFusion?

Tags: csv, coldfusion

What I'm trying to do is

A User puts in a Date
They press a Download Button, this runs a query generating the results for the date they entered. While doing this it is writing these files to my server as .CSV. I will end up zipping them and the file will start downloading as a zip.

I have the code working to write the query to our server but my problem is it puts it all into one big file, where I would like to have the results separated in 2000 results per file. Is this possible? If so how do I go about this?

Current code I have for the query and writing data to server. Some things adjusted.

```
<cfquery name="users" datasource="#request.db#">
    SELECT DISTINCT firstname
    FROM Users
    WHERE Users.Date=#Date#
</cfquery>

<cfset filePath="D:/Users/Users.csv">
<cfset content = "firstname">

<cffile
    action="write"
    file="#filePath#"
    output="#content#">

<cfoutput query="users">
    <cfset content = "">
    <cfset content = "#firstname#">
    <cffile
        action="append"
        file="#filePath#"
        output="#content#">
</cfoutput>

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=#getFileFromPath (filePath)#">
<cfcontent file="#filePath#" type="application/octet-stream" deletefile="yes">
```

This code will run the query, writing the file to server and automatically download. But only downloads and writes to one file. How do I separate it into multiple small result files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coldfusion, help creating a download all button that will zip all the CSV files that are created from a query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626072/coldfusion-help-creating-a-download-all-button-that-will-zip-all-the-csv-files)

Comment: That is actually my other thread, I'm doing it a different way and the way I was breaking it into the 2000 doesn't work this way :/

Comment: It sounds like you want to write all the files, then use `<cfzip>` and then do the `Content-Disposition` part on the resulting zip file

Comment: Yes, but how can I separate the query results into multiple files first? For example if the query returns 4000 results, there would be 2 csv files in the zip that had 200 results each.

Comment: I wouldn't suppose an `xlsx` / `<cfspreadsheet>` is an option. xlsx files are naturally zipped.

Comment: I would like to use the xlsx but the user that requested this wanted the files to be csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<cfset maxrows = 2000>
<cfset onrow = 1>
<cfset filen = 1>
<cfset filelist = "">
<cfloop condition="#onrow# lte #users.recordcount#">
  <cfsavecontent variable="MakeContents"><cfoutput query="users" startrow="#onrow#" maxrows="#maxrows#">#firstname#
</cfoutput></cfsavecontent>
  <cfset MakeContents = trim(MakeContents)><!--- trimming gets rid of an extraneous return at the end of makecontents --->
  <cfset filepath = "d:\users\users_#filen#.csv">
  <cfset onrow = onrow + maxrows>
  <cfset filelist = listAppend(filelist,"users_#filen#.csv")>
  <cffile...> <!---write MakeContents to a file--->
  <cfset filen = filen + 1>
</cfloop>

<cfzip...>
  <cfloop list="#filen#" index="fi">
    <cfzipparam source="d:\users\#fi#">
  </cfloop>
</cfzip>
```

This puts everything for the result set into a variable, writes the variable to a file and stores the file in a list.

After all the file creation is done, cfzip gets all the files by looping over the list.

You can either add a unique identifier to the filename and keep them, or you can delete them afterwards.

Comment: I like the use of `<cfsavecontent>` for the csv string generation

Comment: Edit: Think I got it to work using this way will verify in a second.

Comment: Seems to be breaking it apart correctly, only question now is how do I add the new lines back in? Taking the trim off doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you have the `</cfsavecontent>`  (closing tag) on a seperate line after the `#Firstname#`, as I have it in my demo? If not, do so.

Comment: Great that did the trick, now to get the zip to working and I will be set thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking to do something like this?

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#users.recordcount#" step="2000" index="section">


  <cfoutput query="users" startrow="#section#" maxrows="2000">

    <cfset content = "#firstname#">
    <cffile
        action="append"
        file="#filePath##section#.csv"
        output="#content#">
  </cfoutput>

</cfloop>
```

...

Then zip resulting files

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for, the only thing with this is it stops will do the 2000 then just stop instead of going onto 2001-4000

Comment: Are you saying you have a version of ColdFusion where `<cfoutput>` does not have the `startrow` attribute? Or that startrow does not work?

Comment: It does work, but when I tried this it would just do 2000 results and be done. Instead of continuing to the next 2000 results.

Comment: Do a cfoutput on just the section variable and confirm that it is iterating as expected